# Как посчитать количество символов в тексте?

Tags: c

Пробовал 2 варианта, через размер файла(fseek), и через цикл while(fgetc(file) != EOF. С файлом с английскими словами возвращает все правильно. С русскими же в 2 раза больше. Можно ли как нибудь сделать, чтобы независимо от языка он возвращал верное кол во символов?

Comment: А текст в какой кодировке?

Comment: Я так понял русские символы это UNICODE? Создаю обычный *.txt. Посмотрел сколько весит один английский символ - 1 байт. Русский символ же весит - 2 байта в моей программе

Comment: Все ответ ниже с wchar помог. Странно что один компилятор не хотел считать символы, а другой посчитал их

Comment: Ваш текстовый файл может быть в UTF-8 (скорее всего) или в ANSI-1251 или в UTF-16 или в ещё какой экзотической кодировке. И в зависимости от того, какая используется кодировка в файле, один символ будет занимать то или иное количество байт. Причём, в зависимости от символа и кодировки, число байт занимаемых этим символом может отличаться от числа байт, занимаемых другим символом в этой же кодировки (кодировка с переменным числом байт на символ). Соответственно, и считать символы можно только зная кодировку текста.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте UTF-8 символы с помощью `fgetwc`. Работает только с указанной локалью.

```
NAME
       fgetwc, getwc - read a wide character from a FILE stream

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <wchar.h>

       wint_t fgetwc(FILE *stream);
       wint_t getwc(FILE *stream);

DESCRIPTION
       The  fgetwc()  function  is the wide-character equivalent of
       the fgetc(3) function.  It reads a wide character
       from stream and returns it.  If the end of stream is reached,
       or if ferror(stream) becomes  true,  it  returns
       WEOF.  If a wide-character conversion error occurs, it sets 
       errno to EILSEQ and returns WEOF.
```

getwc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
FILE * const f = fopen("test","r");
do{
errno=0;
wint_t const wc = fgetwc(f);
if (wc == WEOF) {
  if(errno)
    printf("error\n");
  else
    printf("eof\n");
  break;}
printf("wc=%d\n",wc);
} while (1);
fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Разве utf8 использует широкие символы? Он вроде использует пары символов, но не широкие.

Comment: Написал такую функцию:
int get_sym(FILE* fi, int symb)
{
    while (fgetwc(fi) != EOF) {
        symb++;
        printf("%d\n", symb);
    }
    return symb;
}
И если использовать такой fgetwc то даже в цикл while не заходит

Comment: Нужно указывать локаль, тогда пашет.